# Why can't I read what's on the serial port after writing on it from a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, serial-port

Here is my code simplified:

```
> [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames() #to get all the port names 
COM1
COM2
COM3
```

```
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort "COM1",9600,None,8,one
$port.Open()
$port.Write("Hey")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3000 #I wait to make sure it gets written
$port.ReadExisting()
```

Nothing is returned.

Why does it return nothing when it's supposed to return "Hey"?
How can I properly write on the port and read it?

Comment: Your code works for me while connected locally to a Cisco router.

Comment: Thank you for your input. That tells me the problem is probably not from the code but from the PC then.